# What's the point of image_url on AdCreative object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm still very much a Facebook Ad API n00b so I have no idea if this is a good question or not, but on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/creative-specs/ there is a field called: "image_url" Why?  I'm populating this value with a link to an image that is for sure accessible via the web and yet it's being ignored when I attempt to create a new ad.  Any ideas what that point of this field is if it seems to be ignored?  Why force devs to go though this complicated image upload process if that field is exposed?  Perhaps the API can actually pull that image for us and use it or am I totally misunderstanding the point of that field?

Thanks!
Erick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm populating this value with a link to an image that is for sure accessible via the web and yet it's being ignored when I attempt to create a new ad. Any ideas what that point of this field is if it seems to be ignored?

Because you have to **upload** an image with the request, not just point to some URL.

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adimage/

Comment: Thanks for your extremely rapid response.  I'll make some adjustments to my code and work on uploading the image (DUH! This might also explain why the image wasn't showing up in the library.)  thanks CBore!  BTW: Love your "Karma" statement on your profile. :D